# Is it just me or does this word [] look odd to you too?

Tags: discussion, formatting, font

On my computer the word "" in this question looks as though it is boldfaced but in fact it appears to come pre-formatted. Does it look boldfaced to you too? It actually is non-formatted.

It was originally in the title as well as the content, but OP changed the title. I was surprised to find out OP didn't use the formatting tool provided in SE's text box. I copied and pasted it to non-formatted text editors such as notepad, then copied and pasted it back to a text box, and it remains seemingly boldfaced. And what puzzles me is that regardless of whether the text box this word appears in is formatted the word appears the same, always in bold/strong.

Does it look the same to you? How can a word remain boldfaced in all environments?

[In which parts of speech this word belongs to?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/232631/in-which-parts-of-speech-this-word-belongs-to)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ԩ  doesn’t have any special formatting applied either, it’s just a Unicode character copied from another source. Most    that ““ is from a set like these

https://unicodelookup.com/#bold/1

Just replace it with plain text and bold it with the Markdown formatting. It messes up the ability to find the question with search otherwise.

I found [a tool to convert UTF-8 encoded characters](https://onlineutf8tools.com/?msg10) to various other encodings. Here is that "likely" string converted to HTML entities:

𝗹𝗶𝗸𝗲𝗹𝘆 (`&#x1d5f9;&#x1d5f6;&#x1d5f8;&#x1d5f2;&#x1d5f9;&#x1d606;`)

Looking up one of those codes, I find "[mathematical sans-serif bold small l](https://unicodelookup.com/#0x1d5f9/1)".

Comment: Weird Unicode like this also breaks my built in dictionary :/

Comment: @Laurel Can you explain how you did that?

Comment: @AIQ On iOS it's select the word, press, and then tap "Look up". On Mac it's either three finger tap or highlight, right click, and select "Look up".